# Monitoring with jProfiler 8 too many connections

Tags: java, performance, database-connection, connection-pooling, jprofiler

I'm trying to find out a performance issue in my client. They have one instance of jboss 4.0.4 with 18 WAR projects inside. I don't know which one is causing the performance issue, but I discover something a bit stranger in open connections monitoring, but I don't know if the profiler is right and my understanding is right too.

I started the jProfiler at 8:00 AM and until 16:00 the JVM was monitoring 30 to 40 open connections, but after that something occurs ant the jProfiler (version 8) detected 700 open connections! but what was my problem, I can't discover what is opening this connections because there are 0 events and the open connection description just show a connection open by org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.PoolFiller.run()

I understand that this is not a normal behavior, this connections are opening all the time, when one is closed because it gets idles (3 minutes pool idle timeout) another one is created, what can it be? how can I find the caller of those connections? this connections is opened from pool (min-pool-size) ?

all of then have 0 events and appears they are opening automatic outside the application.

Comment: this 700 connections appears to be the "min-pool-size" configuration that reaches exactly 700, but the min-pool-size should open the connections?, in the documentation says that the pool will not be opened until a request: "min-pool-size : This element specifies the minimum number of connections a pool should hold. These pool instances are not created until an initial request for a connection is made. This default to 0."

Comment: "and the open connection description just show a connection open by org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.PoolFiller.run()" I would say that answers the question. The pool creates all those connections for some reason and nothing is done with them. You could try to add "org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager." to the filter and look at the JBoss code in the call tree view to try to understand what is going on in the pool.